# TypeScript Conditionally Merge Prop Types Using Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Compiler tells me that properties `propA` and `propB` inside `TestComponent` don't exist on type `Props<T>`. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about conditional types?

```
import React from 'react';

type PropsBase<T extends boolean | undefined> = {
  isA?: T;
};

type PropsA = {
  propA: string;
};

type PropsB = {
  propB: string;
};

type Props<T extends boolean | undefined> = PropsBase<T> & (T extends false | undefined ? PropsB : PropsA);

function TestComponent<T extends boolean | undefined = true>(props: Props<T>) {
  if (props.isA) {
    return <>{props.propA}</>; // Property 'propA' does not exist
  }
  if (!props.isA) {
    return <>{props.propB}</>; // Property 'propB' does not exist
  }

  return <></>;
}

<>
  <TestComponent propA="propA" /> // Should be valid
  <TestComponent isA propA="propA" /> // Should be valid
  <TestComponent isA={false} propB="propB" /> // Should be valid
  <TestComponent isA propB="propB" /> // Should be invalid
</>
```

My goal was to create an extendable and reusable type which properties can be controlled through generics. I know this is also done with unions, but it's not quite easy to build other types on top of it.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-k8zrA+TC3Bi1GY+XFEmU673XcvVngkrO-lu8GixGB2XbOIE8PKzagA).

Answer (score 1):

I think your first example of `<TestComponent propA="propA" />` should also be invalid? After all, in that case, ìsA`is of type`undefined`.

I changed your `Props<T>` into this `Props` instead:

```js
type Props = ({ isA: true } & PropsA) | ({ isA?: false } & PropsB);

function TestComponent(props: Props) {
    if (props.isA) {
        return props.propA; // OK
    }
    if (!props.isA) {
        return props.propB; // OK
    }
}
```

Your usage of it is also validated properly now:

```js
TestComponent({ propA: 'propA' }); // Property 'isA' is missing
TestComponent({ propB: 'propB' }); // OK
TestComponent({ isA: true, propA: 'propA' }); // OK
TestComponent({ isA: false, propB: 'propB' }); // OK
TestComponent({ isA: true, propB: 'propB' }); // 'propB' does not exist
```

Interestingly, if I use `prop.isA === true`, TypeScript behaves better:

```js
function TestComponent(props: Props) {
    if (props.isA === true) {
        return props.propA; // OK
    }
    const isA = props.isA; // type `false | undefined`
    if (!props.isA) {
        return props.propB; // OK
    }
}
```

That should be good enough in your case I hope? Although I'm surprised in the difference between `if (props.isA)` and `if (props.isA === true)`. Mind that this requires TypeScript to run in strict mode, with `noImplicitAny` enabled to be specific. Otherwise you need to use `if (props.isA === true)`. Weird, but running with `noImplicitAny` disabled is very rare anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `<TestComponent propA="propA" />` works because it's by default `true` in `<T extends boolean | undefined = true>`. Actually it correctly validates component props, the problem is they aren't recognized inside the function. I'm aware it works with unions, but I'm particularly interested if it's possible to get done with generics.

Comment: @eugenics Ah I missed the `= true` part. To be fair, even though the generic type is `true` by default, 
`props.isA` won't be. Not sure it's really possible with generics. _Maybe_ with overloaded functions, but not too hopeful.